# Shimming classes appears to work differently between visual studio and TFS runs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

**TL;DR version**

Shimming a class that inherits from a class that inherits from class we're shimming doesn't shim properly, but only in tfs test runner, or analyze unit test code coverage (at least this is what we've been able to deduce)

**Details**

I'm somewhat new to to shimming and fakes, but have a general understanding of whats going on, and how to set it up.

We've got a good amount of unit tests that utilize shimming to run and verify functionality etc.

THE PROBLEM

We've noticed that some tests fail (only when running code analysis with analyze unit test coverage, or on our build servers). Also, it seems the functionality only fails when dealing with a class that is a subclass of a class we have shims setup for.

EG
ShimServiceBase appears to shim classes that inherit directly from ServiceBase, but if I have a child class of a class that inherits from ServiceBase, that doesn't work, and it only doesnt work in code analysis or tfs unit test runner).

I hope thats enough information or rings a bell with someone somewhere, I believe we could get rid of our class inheritance, but seems like we should be able to shim these classes without having to adjust our code inheritance.

Anyone happen to have any clues?

Comment: Some example code of the failing test would help.

Comment: maybe I need to build a super simple test case